# Shell script multi-line comment

Tags: shell, sed

I am having a large shell script file.  At times while doing modification I want to comment out part of it.  But commenting line as shown in the below example is giving me error.

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
<<COMMENT1
read build_label
read build_branch_tag
build_date_tag=$(echo $build_label | sed "s/$build_branch_tag//g")
echo $build_path
COMMENT1
echo "HELLO WORLD"
```

Error Message:

> sed: first RE may not be empty

I just want to understand what's wrong with the above script and why comment section is not working properly.

Comment: Can you try adding a `:` and single quotes before the `<<COMMENT1`? So it will look like: `: <<'COMMENT1'`

Comment: @ryekayo:  Thanks for your suggestion.  Its seems to be working fine.

Comment: A good explanation can be found here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37411/multiline-shell-script-comments-how-does-this-work however, its safer to use `#` to comment multiple lines and the link I provided will explain why.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, using here docs to comment code is really dirty! Use the `#` instead. If you want to comment multiple lines, use your editor. In vim (commenting lines from 10 to 15 for example):

```
:10,15s/^/#
```

However, to solve your current problem you need to enclose the starting here-doc delimiter in single quotes, like this:

```
<<'COMMENT'
...
COMMENT
```

Using single quotes you tell bash that it should not attempt to expand variables or expression inside the here doc body.

Comment: Oooh, I didn't know you can switch off the expansions by using quotes around the HERE delimiter. Nice!

Comment: Yes it's nice to have! I hope I saved you from some escaping \\ in future.. :)

Answer (score 2):

Traditional UNIX shell doesn't have multiline comment support. What you're doing here is using a so-called "HERE document" without using its value, a common hack to get multiline comment like behaviour.

However, patterns inside the the HERE document are still evaluated, which means that your `$(…)` is executed. But since `build_branch_tag` has not been defined before, it will evaluate to an empty string, and the shell will thus execute `sed s///g`.

You can use a different hack:

```
: '
Bla bla, no $expansion is taking place here.
'
```

What this is doing: the `:` is a no-op command, it simply does nothing. And you're passing it an argument which is a string `'…'`. Inside the single quotes, no expansion/evaluation is taking place. Beware of `'` inside the "commented out" region, though.

Comment: I'd give more emphasis to your last sentence.

Answer (score 1):

You can turn parameter substitution off inside a here document like this:

```
<<"Endofmessage"
```

or

```
<<'Endofmessage'
```

or

```
<<\Endofmessage
```

Here Documents

> This type of redirection instructs the shell to read input from the
>   current source until a line containing only delimiter (with no
>   trailing blanks) is seen. All of the lines read up to that point are
>   then used as the standard input for a command. The format of
>   here-documents is:
>
> <<[-]word
>           here-document delimiter No parameter expansion, command substitution, arithmetic expansion, or pathname expansion is performed
>   on word. If any characters in word are quoted, the delimiter is the
>   result of quote removal on word, and the lines in the here-document
>   are not expanded. If word is unquoted, all lines of the here-document
>   are subjected to parameter expansion, command substitution, and
>   arithmetic expansion. In the latter case, the character sequence
>   \ is ignored, and \ must be used to quote the characters \,
>   $, and `. If the redirection operator is <<-, then all leading tab
>   characters are stripped from input lines and the line containing
>   delimiter. This allows here-documents within shell scripts to be
>   indented in a natural fashion.

And maybe something that you may also like: I prefer to do multiline comments in my bash script with the nodepad++ shortcut ctrl+Q (toggle comment).

Answer (score 0):

if this is not a syntax error (open string, ...)

```
#!/bin/bash

if false;then
read build_label
read build_branch_tag
build_date_tag=$(echo $build_label | sed "s/$build_branch_tag//g")
echo $build_path
fi

echo "HELLO WORLD"
```

if sysntax error or equivalent (unfound place like in search of error by descativate part of failing code)

```
#!/bin/bash

#read build_label
#read build_branch_tag
#build_date_tag=$(echo $build_label | sed "s/$build_branch_tag//g")
#echo $build_path

echo "HELLO WORLD"
```

for this you can use:
- editor if find/replace with regex is available like vi(m)
- a sed (`sed '14,45 s/^/#/' YourFile > YourFile.Debug` where 14 and 45 are first and last lines to comment)

Answer (score 0):

Using here docs to comment code is safe and elegant like this:

```
: <<'EOT'
Example usage of the null command ':' and the here-document syntax for a 
multi-line comment.  If the delimiter word ('EOT' here) is quoted, the 
here-document will not be expanded in any way.  This is important, as 
an unquoted delimiter will result in problems with unintended potential 
expansions.  All of this here-doc text is redirected to the standard input 
of :, which does nothing but return true.  
EOT
```